# Preventing html page to be crawled and cached by bot/crawler

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to prevent web crawlers to crawl and cached my public facing web application website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Robots.txt**:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

But it's not 100% reliable, not all crawlers will respect this.

From what i have learned recently the only 100% reliable way is to make all your pages secure.

Comment: the same for windows server ?

Answer (score 2):

Robots.txt (as already suggested) prevents crawling. If you just want to prevent caching, add the following HTML to your <head> section:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOARCHIVE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [create a robots.txt file](http://www.outfront.net/tutorials_02/adv_tech/robots.htm) in the root of your web site. There are lots of other [interesting tutorials](http://www.clickfire.com/robotstxt-tutorial/) around.

Answer (score 1):

Well a common way to stop search engines like google etc is to include a ROBOTS.TXT file in the root of your website.

Here is a good article on the subject http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/robots.shtml

Answer (score 1):

[Stop crawlers](http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/)